# Oracle Analysis Tool

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a tool or a feature in Oracle SQL Developer where I can get analysis or summary of what indexes are used by the query I manually run or run by a stored procedure ?

I am trying to improve performance of set of queries in SPs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the execution plan sould show you if and when indexes are used.

Run the query with

```
Explain plan FOR
```

at the start